# how would you find $P(Y<X^3)$ on a uniform distribution set

Tags: probability

Let $(X, Y)$ have a uniform distribution on the set $(x, y) : 0< x <2$ and $0< y <8$ and $x < y$.

How would you find $P(Y < X^3)$?

I understand the definition of uniform distribution but Im having a difficult time with the substitution here.

Answer (score 2):

Do this one geometrically:  The allowed area for $(x,y)$ is a trapezoid of base $2$ and parallel sides $8$ (along the $Y$ axis) and $6$ (along the line $x=2$), thus its area is $2\cdot(8+6)/2 = 14$.

The area within that where $y < x^3$ is the area bounded by the point $(1,1)$,
the line $y=x$ from there to the point $(2,2)$, and the curve $y=x^3$ running between $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$, and its area is
$$
\int_{x=1}^2 (x^3-x) dx = \frac{9}4
$$

So the desired probability is $$\frac{9}{56}$$

Comment: That seems easy enough. Thanks. I was having a difficult type visualizing the points in space.

Comment: Note my correction, I forgot to limit it by the bottom line $y=x$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the area of the triangle defined by  $\{(x, y) : 0< x <2, 0< y <8,\text{ and }x < y\}$ is equal to $14$, the density of the Uniform distribution is $1/14$. Then,

$$P(Y<X^3)=\int_1^2\int_x^{x^3}\frac{1}{14}dydx=\int_1^2\frac{x(x^2-1)}{14}dx=\frac{x^2(x^2-2)}{56}\Bigg|_1^2=\frac{9}{56}.$$

Here is a sketchy version of the plot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but as a check of the work above, an R simulation gives

```
x<-runif(10^7,0,2)
y<-runif(10^7,0,8)
z<-cbind(x,y)
z<-subset(z,x<y)
mean(z[,"y"]<z[,"x"]^3)

0.160584

9/56

0.1607143
```

so our empirical result agrees with the analytical results above.